# warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[30]’ [-Wformat=]

Tags: c, struct

I am creating a database with students, I have created a `struct Students`

```
struct Students {
    //struct specific for students
    char first_name[30];
    char last_name[30];
    int ssn;
};

void add_student() {
    //function to add students
    int i, n;
    struct Students *student;
    printf("How many students are you adding");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    student = (struct Students *)malloc(n * sizeof(struct Students *)); //allocate the memory for n students

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter first, last and ssn respectively");
        scanf(" %s ", &(student+i)->first_name); //adds first name to student i
        scanf(" %s ", &(student+i)->last_name);// adds last name to student i
        scanf(" %d ", &(student+i)->ssn); //adds ssn to student i
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //print each of the students being added
        printf("First name: %s\n ", (student+i)->first_name);
        printf("Last name: %s\n ", (student+i)->last_name);
        printf("ssn: %d\n ", (student+i)->ssn);
    }
    free(student); //free the memory used 
}
```

Expected: I am trying to add students for the database and print them 
      out to ensure that they are actually being written to the structs.

Actual:

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[30]’ [-Wformat=]
    scanf(" %s ", &(student+i)->first_name);
```

Comment: The `&` is not needed for `first_name` and `last_name`.

Comment: Does there need to be the free (student) because when I run the program                                                             
 *** Error in `./Project': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000002133830 ***

Comment: That error indicates that memory was corrupted. You're going to need to post a [mcve], including the input that you provided to the program.

Comment: BTW, `(student+i)->` is the same as `student[i].` and the latter is a lot easier to read, imo.

Comment: And don't cast malloc. It's unnecessary in C and can hide other problems.

Comment: @P.M.T: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 4):

Just pass the array as an argument, that will decay into a pointer to its first element:

```
scanf("%s", student[i].first_name);
```

You are passing the address of the array, which has the same value but does not have the same type as as the address of its first element. The compiler detects this type mismatch as issues a warning (which is a **very** good thing!)

Here is a list of other problems in your code:

- You should test the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or missing input.
- Also add validity tests on the values entered with `scanf()`.
- The memory allocated for the array of `Students` is incorrect: you allocate `n` time the size of a pointer, you should be allocating `n` time the size of the `Student struct` itself.
- Remove the trailing spaces in the `scanf()` format strings. These cause extra input to be read for no reason.
- Also Add the maximum number of characters to store into the destination arrays: `"%29s"`.
- Test the return values of `scanf()` to detect missing input.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
struct Students {
    //struct specific for students
    char first_name[30];
    char last_name[30];
    int ssn;
};

void add_student() {
    //function to add students
    int i, n;
    struct Students *student;

    printf("How many students are you adding");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Allocate the memory for n students
    student = malloc(n * sizeof(struct Students));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter first, last and ssn respectively: ");
        if (scanf("%s", student[i].first_name) != 1
        ||  scanf("%s", student[i].last_name) != 1
        ||  scanf("%d", student[i].ssn) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input or missing input\n");
            n = i; // only `i` students have ben read
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // print each of the students being added
        printf("First name: %s\n", student[i].first_name);
        printf("Last name: %s\n", student[i].last_name);
        printf("ssn: %d\n", student[i].ssn);
    }
    free(student); //free the memory used 
}
```

Comment: @M.M: indeed a better format string, among other problems I did not spot at first sight :)

Answer (score 1):

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 
has type ‘char (*)[30]’ [-Wformat=]
```

This **warning** is showing because you using `&` while scanning `(student+i)->first_name` and `(student+i)->last_name`. You don't need to put `&` before variable name while scanning *string*. Note that, `&` is need to use before all the other variable type.

Change this to line:

```
scanf(" %s ", &(student+i)->first_name);
scanf(" %s ", &(student+i)->last_name);
```

To

```
scanf(" %s ", (student+i)->first_name);
scanf(" %s ", (student+i)->last_name);
```

And the warning will gone

Comment: There should not be trailing space in the scanf format string